# Node Js Request Module not Accessing Correct Place on Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to make a script with Node Js' request module which will accept a class subject and number, then go to the ASU course catalog, collect the professors, and get their score on RateMyProfessor, at the moment I am attempting to connect to: https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?t=2201&s=CSE&n=205&e=all&page=1, which is the site for CSE 205, however the script instead goes to https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog, or so I assume as the class subject box is empty.

This is the script at the time of error

```
const url = "https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?t=2201&s=CSE&n=205&e=all&page=1";
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

request({
  uri: url,
  jar: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    const test = $('#subjectEntry').html();
    console.log(test); //Always returns empty rather than "CSE"
  }
})
```

Is there a way to make it go directly to the site with classes? Had it been a form to search for a class I could have worked with that, however it is just regular inputs.
Going to this website on anything else will go to the correct link as well, it seems to only be a problem with Node Js accessing the site. This same problem also occurred with Axios and Puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple the ASU website taking time to load. Since the scraper grabbed the information the second the site was opened, it couldn't find anything. I fixed this simply by creating a sleep function and using it in an async function with await to be sure the site was fully loaded.